# How to open remotely react app with changed HOST file?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, hosts

I have changed etc/hosts file with row: `127.0.0.1 localhost.domain.com`

Then i have this row in scripts:  `"start": "cross-env HOST=localhost.domain.com PORT=3001 HTTPS=true react-scripts start",`

But in this case, i cant open my app on phone remotely via `https://192.168.100.3:3001/`

P.S. If i remove `HOST=localhost.domain.com` from start command everything works fine.

P.S.S. Mac os, ip 192.168.100.3

Answer (score 0):

Simply run HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start.

Afterward, open the URL from another device on the network.

In your case, 192.168.0.5:3000 would work.

You can also check [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md)

Comment: what's the issue ?